# Java While advance x loops

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, rowset

I have a progran in Java. I will illustrate it with a simplified example:

```
while( rowSet.next() ){
   //OPERATIONS
}
```

I know that my row set has length 50. I want to debug row number 48, but for it I dont want to go through the while 48 times.

Do you know how to position my debug in loop 48?

Comment: What is `rowSet`? Not unless it allows random access

Comment: Hi jpdeveloper, welcome to Stack Overflow. We here use something called an MCVE or a Minimal, Complete,Verifiable Example to show our problems. We need to see all of the relevant part of your code to help you, not only the loop. For instance, we need the data type of `rowSet` to know if it supports random access to elements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `rowSet` is a `javax.sql.RowSet`, you may use the `absolute` method to move to a given row number:

```
    rowSet.absolute(48);
    // OPERATIONS
```

The same is possible if `rowSet` is a `java.sql.ResultSet`.